# How to prevent breaking long Hyperlink after hyphen but keep in the parrent DIV

Tags: html, css, layout, hyperlink

I have a problem with a very long hyperlink (a result from DropBox API). 
I would like to place this long hyperlink in a box (DIV) from one side to the next full width. This hyperlink is so long that is multi-line in my layout. This hyperlink has also a lot of hyphens. 
If i put *white-space: nowrap;* there is no wrap and the hyperlink is in one line but goes beyond DIV.
If i dont have this, the hyperlink is broken after a hyphen.

I tried also *display: table-cell;* but it doesn't help.
Code is below and i have also attached a jpg picture with visual explanation what i need to achieve :)

```
<body>

      <div style='width: 800px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>
            <p style='
                  word-wrap: break-word;
                  font-decoration: none; 
                  border-style: solid; 
                  border-width: 1px; '>
                  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/apitl/1/ALk3qJvqL7bxI3Kf0swn4wgFdldncEhgEJT-yiEnWjn4ULarF1YAZrrlVaU7MTcgketcaif9qjwVXOjEWYe4pLhRDIlQdzou4N424G6Xm5l8KoZtHbT8gsRlFhyda9NIvwW-IRTpJOR3sHqRskC8N8knxx4x6jZlDJRkWj3CaMkislOf5SObk5mU42unmVW__jO2hRYEd3jPMixU_MojMM7fD5kHab8smqthpistTG2MlI3xDBxxSC_UWYmgS6f38Rdqd-3MnOwikSFty9ZeH-5qTVCHJrRECSJL07CT1PXHxslI0Bavs_hcNowNbnWi_ToiTenKCJHrcFkw7fVi7yJZuQ-HFccIWQHMAFOIx5vCMA 
            </p>
      </div>

      <div style='width: 800px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>
            <p style='
                  word-wrap: break-word;
                  white-space: nowrap;
                  font-decoration: none; 
                  border-style: solid; 
                  border-width: 1px;'>
                  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/apitl/1/ALk3qJvqL7bxI3Kf0swn4wgFdldncEhgEJT-yiEnWjn4ULarF1YAZrrlVaU7MTcgketcaif9qjwVXOjEWYe4pLhRDIlQdzou4N424G6Xm5l8KoZtHbT8gsRlFhyda9NIvwW-IRTpJOR3sHqRskC8N8knxx4x6jZlDJRkWj3CaMkislOf5SObk5mU42unmVW__jO2hRYEd3jPMixU_MojMM7fD5kHab8smqthpistTG2MlI3xDBxxSC_UWYmgS6f38Rdqd-3MnOwikSFty9ZeH-5qTVCHJrRECSJL07CT1PXHxslI0Bavs_hcNowNbnWi_ToiTenKCJHrcFkw7fVi7yJZuQ-HFccIWQHMAFOIx5vCMA 
            </p>
      </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[What i need PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgKEV.jpg)

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Best, Michal

Comment: It really would help if you showed us an example of your HTML.

Comment: Thank you for support :) Its my first post here :)

Comment: Please provide full HTML, not just the div that holds the link. Provide HTML that has the link already inside of it with it's parent divs.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have updated my post :)